# How to add chatter on home page in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning

I want add feed and groups on my lightning home page for logged in user i.e chatter functionality on home page.
I have tried to get chatter on home page by adding VF Page

But we get only feeds not groups.

How can I add chatter functionality on my lightning home page ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a VF Page as

```html
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >
  <chatter:feed entityId="{!$User.Id}"/>
</apex:page>
```

And add the above VF Page on lightning home page.